# ViewModel in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working on a project and was wondering if anyone else has messed with the view model much. Im looking for some examples on how to inject other view models i.e header,footer content.

I already have the template and layout path switching Im just trying to figure out the best way to handle if I select layout1 and it has 3 footer content fields, and a slider so how would put a class in front of the render to gather and inject required data

**EDIT**
Ok I guess I should clarify LOL .... slight ADHD where my mind wanders.

What should I listen for before injecting the viewmodels or can I do this in my onBootStrap() in my main module. I currently

```
$sites = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Application\Model\Sites');
$sr = $sites->getSiteByDomain();
```

Since many domains and/or subdomains can point to this and puts info in a session. Maybe im over thinking it and should just extend actionController like I did in ZF1

LOL PHP so many ways to do something ......

Thx for any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two helpful links i can give you. One is the playground of Rob Allen alias Akrabat, you can find his playground right [over here at github](https://github.com/akrabat/ZF2TestApp/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/ViewController.php). The other one would be the official documentation which is [nicely documented](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html) on this part.

If those don't help you, you should specify your question and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thx Sam, I have those bookmarked and have been over them. Ill edit my question for more detail

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for the links. They lead me in the right direction to get the answers that I needed. Also helped me write a much more concise solution that what I was previously.